error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!: adr X1, msg
I am working on a hello world program in arm64 assembly on my apple silicon mac. Here is my code:
.global _start
.align 4

_start:
//write function call
    mov     X0, #0 //standard output file
    adr     X1, msg //loading message
    mov     X2, #13 //13 is length of msg
    mov     X16, #4 //4 is the write call
    svc     #0x80

//exit function call
    mov     X0, #0 //return 0
    mov     X16, #1 //1 is the exit function call
    svc     #0x80

.data
    msg: .ascii "Hello World!\n"

At first the code was running, but not printing anything (as it currently is) then randomly (I'm pretty sure) I was getting this error when running: error: unknown AArch64 fixup kind!: adr X1, msg. I can't tell what the error is.
Honestly I tried rearranging the registers, I added adr X1, =msg, I tried making it adr X1, .ascii "Hello World!\n". I also tried changing the system calls, but I think the error is in the adr. So then I tried using ldr, add, and adrp`, but nothing worked.
